# AWS cloudformation domain names and API mappings

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, aws-api-gateway

I have a domain name **example.com** and a lambda backend with api gateway set up with cloud formation and code pipeline with the following yaml template:

```
 PostSomeApi:
      Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
      Properties:
       Handler: lambda_function.lambda_handler
       Runtime: python3.8
       FunctionName: some-api-name
       CodeUri: ./src/some-api-name 
       Role: !Ref LambdaRoleArn
       Timeout: 45
       Environment:
        Variables:
          accountId: !Ref "AWS::AccountId"
          region:    !Ref "AWS::Region"
       Events:
        SampleApi:
         Type: Api
         Properties:
          Path: /someapiname
          Method: POST
```

I connected the subdomain api.example.com to lambda api gateway with **manual configuration** on the console but now I want to include this API mapping in the cloud formation yaml template.

How can I do this?
[This is the manual configuration of the api mapping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1tDxS.png)

Comment: How did it go? Still unclear what you can do?

Comment: Hello thanks for asking I manged to make an AWS::Serverless::Api, and a domain, but then I-m still struggling with API mappings:
MyDomainDev:
 Type: AWS::ApiGateway::DomainName
 Properties: 
  DomainName: api-dev.example.com
  CertificateArn: !Sub 'arn:aws:acm:us-east-1:${AWS::AccountId}:certificate/a2c90924-*****'
  EndpointConfiguration:
   Types:
    - EDGE
  SecurityPolicy: TLS_1_2

Comment: SampleFunction:
 Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
 Properties:
    Handler: Index.lambda_handler
    Runtime: python3.7
    FunctionName: SamplePython
    CodeUri: ./src/nominal #Directory the source file is
    Role: !Sub arn:aws:iam::${AWS::AccountId}:role/LambdaRole
    Environment:
   Variables:
    accountId: !Ref "AWS::AccountId"
    region: !Ref "AWS::Region"
 Events:
  SampleApi:
  Type: Api
  Properties:
   Path: /sample-test
   Method: GET
   RestApiId: 
    Ref: SampleApi

Comment: SampleApi:
 Type: AWS::Serverless::Api
 Properties:
  StageName: Test
  OpenApiVersion: '2.0'
  Domain: MyDomainDev

Comment: `APIMapping: Type: AWS::ApiGateway::BasePathMapping 
Properties: 
BasePath: example ( or empty ) 
DomainName: api-dev.example.com 
RestApiId: SampleApi 
Stage: dev`

Comment: How did it go? Still unclear what you can do?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing this manually, you have to create `AWS::Serverless::Api`, where you can provide [DomainConfiguration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-property-api-domainconfiguration.html).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. 
Do you mean to replace: `Events: SampleApi: Type: Api Properties: Path: /someapiname Method: POST` that is creating the APIGateway, with `AWS::Serverless::Api `? could you please place a sample code?

Comment: @philiot Yes. You create your own AWS::Serverless::Api.